# Convert from IO Maybe a to EitherT IO a

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm working with the [servant](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant) library for an API. It runs in the: `EitherT (Int, String) IO a` monad. I have a function with the type `IO Maybe a`, and would like to use it.

Here's an example that works:

```
sourcesGetAll :: EitherT (Int, String) IO [Source]
sourcesGetAll = liftIO $ sourcesList h

sourcesList :: IO [Source]
```

But now I want to use these two functions together

```
sourcesFind :: IO (Maybe Source)
sourcesGetOne :: EitherT (Int, String) IO Source
sourcesGetOne = ???
```

I would like to do this:

```
maybeNotFound :: Maybe a -> Either (Int, String) a
maybeNotFound Nothing = Left (404, "Not Found")
maybeNotFound Just a  = Right a
```

How do I do that with all the fancy monads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`hoistEither :: Monad m => Either a b -> EitherT a m b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.3.3.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#v:hoistEither) to implement this:

```
maybeNotFoundT :: IO (Maybe a) -> EitherT (Int, String) IO a
maybeNotFoundT maAct = do
  ma <- liftIO maAct -- get the Maybe a. Now ma :: Maybe a
  hoistEither $ maybeNotFound ma
```

Answer (score 4):

You can decompose this into two separate problems:

- Transform `IO (Maybe a)` into `MaybeT IO a`
- Transform `MaybeT IO a` into `EitherT (Int, String) a`

The first one is solved by using the `MaybeT` constructor:

```
MaybeT :: IO (Maybe a) -> MaybeT IO a
```

The second is solved by using `noteT` from the `errors` library:

```
noteT :: Monad m => a -> MaybeT m b -> EitherT a m b
```

Comment: I suppose this won't work with `errors 2.0` since that switches to ExceptT instead of EitherT?

Comment: Correct.  `errors-2.0` will use `ExceptT` instead of `EitherT`

Answer (score 1):

Another answer thanks to mpickering on freenode:

```
sourcesGetOne = EitherT $ maybeNotFound <$> sourcesFind
```

> So the question is how to write a function.. `IO (Maybe a) -> EitherT (Int, String) IO a`
>   Given a function `f :: Maybe a -> Either (Int, String) a`, then one way is..
>
> `myFunc action = EitherT (f <$> action)`
>
> If you look at the docs for EitherT -- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.3.3.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html. Then you'll see that `EitherT (Int, String) IO a`, is actually just a wrapped up `IO (Either (Int, String) a)`